# implementing one to many relation between 2 dimensions in dataware house

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse

I am designing a Dataware house for the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) job section. I have two dimensions: **job opportunity and company**. every record of job opportunity is referenced to **only one** record of company dimension. there are two ways to implement this relationship.

first:
[image: design1]
second:
[image]

I doubt which approach is better. can anyone help?

Comment: First. With unique coinstraint on `job_opportunity.company_id`.

Comment: @Akina why unique constraint is needed? I only need to mention it is a foreign key. a company can have multiple job opportunity.

Comment: *why unique constraint is needed?* You tell ***one and only one*** - without this constraint one may insert one more record into `job_opportunity` referenced to the same record in `company`.

Comment: @Akina sorry it was my mistake. I fixed it

Comment: If so you do not need in UNIQUE constrain. Relation will be 1:N, intermediate table is excess except the link is an entity itself.